# Raising Alert Level in Paradroid

Tags: paradroid

I once played a lot the game PARADROID 90 for the Commodore Amiga, and I finished the game a lot of times, but I was never able to raise the Alert Level by my own conscious actions, sometimes it turned Yellow, but I don't know why.

Does anyone know the trigger behind raising the Alert Level on the game?

Comment: Question: what is so wrong with best regards and why did you clear amiga (when it can be a filter for people who only care about amiga games and not have the paradroid filter)?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts explains the reason "best regards" got removed.  As you can see from https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12349/do-we-really-need-this-longplay-tag Arqade avoids meta tags like Amiga.

Comment: About tagging with [amiga]: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless